# How to get product image for POST method in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I need product image for POST method how will get this data i have tried but i'm not getting please see my code and help me i'm a new in opencart.

Here my controller file code:controller/product/product.php

```
//------first type-------//

$fields = array(
                'image' => urlencode($_POST['image'])
                );
//------first type close-------//

//------2nd type-------//
           if (isset($this->request->post['image'])) {
                    $data['image'] = $this->request->post['image'];
                } else {

                   $data['image'] = $this->request->post['image'];
            }
//------2nd type close-------//
```

Comment: try this if (isset($this->request->post['image'])) {
                    $data['image'] = $this->request->post['image'];
                } else {

                   $data['image'] ='';
            }